# How to avoid table name confusion during a join where the table names are the same

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

I have a model that looks like this:

```
author: id, name, lastname
books: id, name, author_id
```

When I do a join request:

```
SELECT author.*, books.*
FROM author
LEFT JOIN books ON books.author_id = author.id
```

It is not clear what the column name refers to in my result set.

I can fix that by doing:

```
SELECT author.*, books.*, author.name as `author_name`, books.name as `book_name`
...
```

But I don't want to explicit each field alias. What I would like to do is something like that:

```
SELECT author.* as `author_.*`, books.* as `books_.*`
...
```

so that I have the columns `author_id, author_name, ..., book_name, ...`

But it doesn't work. How do you avoid the name confusion ? Do I have to specify the alias for each field ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution to your problem if you don't want to add an `ALIAS` on the columns is to ***rename it to avoid name collision***.

Comment: In my example, you would replace book.name by book.title. But in my application I have lots and lots of table. I would end up with fields like table_x_created_at, table_y_created_at, which I really don't like.

Comment: That, use prefixes on the field names like `book_id` and `book_name` when you define the tables to avoid situations like this, and stop using `SELECT *`.

Comment: @pinouchon and that's the only way. try it on [SQLFiddle.com](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) without supplyinh the alias and you will see the duplicated column name won't show.

Answer (score 0):

The output will only show the field names (or an alias specified in the query), not the table name.  Either change the model to have fields like 'author_name', 'book_name', or use aliases in the query.